# Google Cloud Platform: How do I verify the domain for a static website to be hosted on Bucket?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want a static/html Website to be hosted on [Google Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website). Let's say `example.com` to be hosted on Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

But then Google is asking me to [verify domain ownership](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification#verification) by UPLOADING A FILE onto the site?

But as I mentioned, I want to host the website inside the Google Bucket. Then how do I upload the file without having the Bucket first? This is becoming a chicken and egg problem to me.

Someone help me with this step, please.

Answer (score 1):

Google support several methods to validate domain control.

Since you do not have a website setup yet, chose the `Domain name provider` method. Using this method you create a special DNS TXT record in your DNS server. Google reads this DNS TXT record which verifies that you have control of the domain name.

[Google Verification Methods](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179)

Answer (score 0):

It can be problem if you want to also use Cloud DNS to host your site.
I'm not sure Cloud DNS let's you set up a zone for a domain you haven't verified so it can indeed become a chicken and egg problem.

Solution for me was that my registrar had a few extra options like hosting a small DNS zone directly at the registrar, or redirecting the domain to a different one so I could use an existing website to upload the verification data. Or of course set up a temporary DNS server for the purpose.

But again, it's unclear to me if Cloud DNS will let you set up a zone without having verified the domain. Otherwise it would be possible to hijack a domain simply by creating a Cloud DNS zone for it before the legit owner (assuming owner and attacker both use Cloud DNS so the SOA record points at the same DNS servers for owner and attacker).

Although it's also possible that properly setting up DNSSec is a valid proof that the zone is tied to the legit owner. No idea if that counts though.